# Calling method from presentingViewController using UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a controller, lets call it `mainController` that belongs to a tab-button in my `UITabNarController`. Now, within `mainController`, i load a new viewController, lets call it `secondViewController` like so:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
secondViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Which works fine. But within `secondViewController`, i wish to call a method from `mainController`, like so:

```
 [((mainController*)self.presentingViewController) aMethod];
```

In the past, i never used UITabBarController and this works fine. However, now i get an error

```
[UITabBarController aMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Why does `presentingViewController` respond with `UITabBarController`?

Answer (score 2):

This feels a little hackish but you could get a reference to your mainController with [(UITabBarController *)self.presentingViewController selectedViewController]. If that doesn't work, or you don't want to do it that way, then using delegation is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's because your mainController isn't set to provide presentation context and the search go up the hierarchy until it finds something like UITabBarController which provides it.

Try setting `definesPresentationContext` to YES on your `mainController` before calling `presentViewController`. 
If that doesn't help try also setting `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`

See documentation below:

> A Boolean value that indicates whether this view controller's view is
>   covered when the view controller or one of its descendants presents a
>   view controller.
>
> @property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL definesPresentationContext
>
> Discussion
>
> When a view controller is presented, iOS starts with the
>   presenting view controller and asks it if it wants to provide the
>   presentation context. If the presenting view controller does not
>   provide a context, then iOS asks the presenting view controller’s
>   parent view controller. iOS searches up through the view controller
>   hierarchy until a view controller provides a presentation context. If
>   no view controller offers to provide a context, the window’s root view
>   controller provides the presentation context.
>
> If a view controller returns YES, then it provides a presentation
>   context. The portion of the window covered by the view controller’s
>   view determines the size of the presented view controller’s view. The
>   default value for this property is NO.

Comment: Hmm  `[((mainController*)self.presentingViewController) aMethod];` is still returning `UITabBarController`

Comment: Try also setting `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`

Comment: Same issue. Its weird because im doing `[self presen...` which should mean `mainViewController` is the presentingviewconroller

Comment: Perhaps you should think of redesigning your application, think why would you need to do anything on parent `viewController`? If it's not displaying any `views` then there shouldn't be anything to do there. If you want to update something then you have methods like viewWillAppear which is called once you go back. Perhaps you should move aMethod to some model so you could access that method from any `viewController`.

Comment: secondViewController allows the user to select items from a list. I need to add/remove these items into/from an array in viewcontroller. im fine with my current design. I feel like this task of calling a method from the controllers parent should be a fairly common task, though not much on google about it

Comment: If you operate on some array from mainViewController you can subclass your secondViewController and set that array reference before doing transition. Then in secondViewController you could operate on that array directly.

Comment: You may also consider using delegation. Before transition you could set mainViewController as delegate of secondViewController so in case of choosing something in secondViewController you would call delegate function which would tell your mainViewController that selection has been made.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of the following?

```
NSLog(@"Presenting View controller: %@", [self.presentingViewController class]);
```